# Why does the Tokio Hello World panic with "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

This is the sample hello world program [from the Tokio documentation](https://tokio.rs/docs/getting-started/hello-world/) .

```
use tokio::prelude::*;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:6142").await.unwrap();
    println!("created stream");

    let result = stream.write(b"hello world\n").await;
    println!("wrote to stream; success={:?}", result.is_ok());
}
```

Which gives me this error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 10061, kind: ConnectionRefused, message: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it." }', src\libcore\result.rs:1165:5
stack backtrace:
.
.
.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have a server running at `127.0.0.1:6142`?

Comment: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seemingly didn't follow the instructions for the hello world, thus you get an error because there's no server listening:

> Install [`socat`](https://tokio.rs/docs/network-utilities/socat), which is a network utility that we’ll use to simulate a server. Then type the following command to print out everything that is received on port 6142 (a somewhat arbitrary number we have chosen for this example):
>
> ```
> socat TCP-LISTEN:6142,fork stdout
> ```